# What is the proper way of initializing nullable state in React/TypeScript apps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

What is the proper way to initialize initial empty(null) state in React, using TypeScript interfaces/types?
For example, I have an interface:

```
interface IObject {
  name: string,
  age: number,
  info: IAnotherObject
}
```

and a simple component, where I want to define `initial information state as null`(w/o creating a class that implements my interface and shape default values for all properties), but with `IObject` interface

```
interface IState {
  information: null|IObject;
}

class App extends React.Component<{}, IState> {
 state = {
  information: null
 };

 componentDidMount() {
  // fetch some data and update `information` state
 }

 render() {
   <div>
    {this.state.information &&
    <div>
      <div>{this.state.information.name}</div>
      <div>//other object data</div>
    </div>
   </div>
 }
```

Do we have another way to initialize nullable state w/o using `union` type:

```
// worked way, but with union null type
interface IState {
  information: null|IObject;
}
// some another way(no union), but with initial `null` or `undefined`
interface IState {
  information: IObject;
}

state = {
 information: null
}
```

(it's seems not very "smart" for me to annotate with `null` every object which I want to have initial empty value)type object in state?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have initial empty state, you should to do this,

Mark information as empty,

```
interface IState {
  information?: IObject;
}
```

now you can initialize it as empty.

```
state = {}
```

You should rely on `undefined` instead of `null` for missing properties. From typescript style guide, ([link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines#null-and-undefined))

> Use undefined. Do not use null.